# I Want to create an item list like PlayStore

Tags: android, view, android-webview, android-adapter

I am trying to make an app for android and need the First page view to be like playstore. It should be showing some items.

[image: one]

How can I make the app look like this.

Like what kind of Adapter I can use.

I Googled a lot but couldn't find the answer. Any type of help will appreciated.

Even if you have any resource link it will be fine.

Comment: You need to use a `Custom GridView` with an `Adapter` and `Object`. Google again and search `How to make a Custom GridView with Adapter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the same by creating custom GridView.

[**Here**](https://www.caveofprogramming.com/guest-posts/custom-gridview-with-imageview-and-textview-in-android.html) is the link for the same.

Just change from this:

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:numColumns="3" >
```

to this:

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:numColumns="2" >
```

If you want two columns.

Answer (score 0):

"Grid Style List" is possible with `RecyclerView`.

```
RecyclerView yourRecyclerView;//make your RecylclerView
YourRecyclerViewAdapter mAdapter;//make your adapter with extends RecyclerView.Adapter<YourRecyclerViewAdapter.YourViewHolder>
mGridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(mContext,2);
yourRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mGridLayoutManager);
yourRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.caveofprogramming.com/guest-posts/custom-gridview-with-imageview-and-textview-in-android.html

take gridview with android:numColumns="2" and in adapter set your all content as per your need